# Evaluating the Center of Mass of hollow objects using triple integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I have been calculating the center of masses of various objects using triple integrals, however, one thing I am struggling is calculating the center of mass of hollow objects. My first approach was to go in a similar fashion as we do for solid objects, however, setting the bounds differently.

For example, for a solid hemisphere with uniform density, the center of mass would be
$$\frac{\frac{M}{\frac43 \pi R ^3}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{R} \rho ^2 \sin \phi \cos \phi d\rho d\phi d\theta}{M}$$
For the c.o.m. of a hollow hemisphere with a similar uniform density, I was thinking of evaluating a similar integral:
$$\frac{\frac{M}{4 \pi R ^2}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{R}^{R + dR} \rho ^2 \sin \phi \cos \phi d\rho d\phi d\theta}{M}$$

where $dR$ indicates the change in radius. I quickly realised that this approach is flawed. What correction should I make to this approach to find the c.o.m. of a hollow body?

Comment: Do we have to account for the thickness? If not a double integral will suffice.

Comment: How does that give the center of mass? The center of mass is an element of $\Bbb{R}^3$. Anyway, if you're dealing with a solid object, then you should use a triple integral. If it's a hollow shell then you should use a double integral.

Comment: @peek-a-boo how so?

Comment: Surface integral,  not double integral. You can also follow the direction you had in mind, doing a limit. However, your integrals are not correct, even if you're doing the $z$-coordinate, and you have to divide by the mass.

Comment: @TedShifrin yeah, I forgot about the mass, my bad. Thanks a lot for pointing that out :)

So for evaluating the integral that I gave, can I set up a limit for dR approaching zero?

Comment: Yes, although I personally would write $\Delta R$ instead.

Comment: gotcha, thanks so much!